# Why class defination after main() function will not work?

Tags: c++, class

If the function is defined after main() function program will work...

```
void printdata(int i);

int main()
{
  printdata(20);
  return 0;
}

void printdata(int i)
{
  std::cout << "i = " << i << std::endl;
}
```

If we declare class before main function and defined after main function, why it will through error?

```
#include <iostream>

class C;

int main()
{
  C c(20);
  c.printdata();
  return 0;
}

class C
{
  int i;

public:
  C(int a) : i(a) {};
  void printdata()
  {
    std::cout << "C:i = " << i << std::endl;
  }
};
```

Error log after compiling the code:

```
class_after_main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
class_after_main.cpp:7:6: error: variable ‘C c’ has initializer but incomplete type
   C c(20);
```

Comment: You have to let any code that uses your class see it's declaration before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you declare a class without defining it, you can only use reference or pointer to that class. The compiler needs to know the size of the class to define the size needed to store its objects.